# Python: Detecting large digits in an image

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract, image-recognition, sift

I am currently working on identifying relevant aspects of a game board in an online card game. I've come very far exclusively using OpenCV's SIFT and FlannBasedMatcher to identify cards based on their artwork. SIFT works for identifying the cost of cards, but I view it as inefficient to use it simply to recognize digits. Tesseract doesn't seem to work due to the nature of the digits, and OpenCV template matching doesn't work due to the digits being rotated. Any suggestions?

[image: Example Image]

Edit: added the unprocessed image

[image: Example Image Unprocessed]

Edit 2: I've tried using pytesseract on correctly rotated cards, but it doesn't give any accurate results for my processing. Here is the return:

paw PoE O ¢ Mls OS,

a) ae»

For the following image:
[image: Example Image Upright]

Comment: I'd like to see that image without all the processing.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Understandable. I've added the unedited image in an edit to the original post.

Comment: ah. they're arranged in a kind of fan. you can take these regions and warp them (rotate) so they're more suitable to tesseract.

Comment: it will help you: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/13/recognizing-digits-with-opencv-and-python/

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz That's very doable, thanks for the suggestion. If you don't mind my asking, do you see the processing I've applied as appropriate? It hasn't worked for an example that I added in another edit, given I didn't use any tesseract configurations.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Ok, I just saw your comment, I'll look into it!

Comment: tesseract needs the glyph shapes themselves, not outlines. use thresholding. do *not* do edge "detection'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the seven Hu invariant moments to recognize shapes. Once you have converted the shapes into the 7 Hu-moment vector, you can use your method of choice to compare the distance or similarity between each vector to evaluate each digit. You may need to create your own baseline Hu-moment representation of each number and use it to compare each digit extracted from the images you process.

You can find more information here:
[Shape Matching using Hu Moments](https://www.learnopencv.com/shape-matching-using-hu-moments-c-python/)

```
def cosine_similarity(a, b):
    return np.dot(a, b)/(np.linalg.norm(a)*np.linalg.norm(b))

file = "QcpmV.png"
image = cv2.imread(file)
# Extract digit 6 from image and calculate Hu-Moments vector
shape_six = image[130:190, 70:120, 0]
six = cv2.HuMoments(cv2.moments(shape_six)).flatten()

# Extract first digit 2 from image and calculate Hu-Moments vector
shape_two = image[80:130, 255:310, 0]
two = cv2.HuMoments(cv2.moments(shape_two)).flatten()

# Extract second digit 2 from image and calculate Hu-Moments vector
shape_two2 = image[45:95, 450:500, 0]
two2 = cv2.HuMoments(cv2.moments(shape_two2)).flatten()

# Euclidean distance between normalized vectors
print(np.linalg.norm((six / two) - np.ones_like(two), np.linalg.norm((two2 / two) - np.ones_like(two)))
# 85.40357529593982 8.24734565595225

# Cosine similarity between normalized vectors
print(cosine_similarity((six / two), two), cosine_similarity((two2 / two), two))
# 0.011080249709150468 0.11637902029940049
```